# vim: <Ctrl-a> behavior in mapping for non-numeric lists

Tags: vim, mapping

In vim, I want to automatically insert a new line with a list leader, using the following mapping.

```
imap <buffer> <C-CR> <ESC>Yp<C-A>WC
```

The idea is to duplicate the current line (`<ESC>Yp`), increase the leading number (`<C-A>`), jump to the next word (`W`) and change the rest of the line (`C`). Example:

```
    1. Hello|<C-CR>
```

gives me

```
    1. Hello
    2. |
```

where `|` is the cursor position and I end up in insert mode.

Since `<C-A>` is a no‐op for for bullet lists, I'd expect it to work exactly the same, but it doesn't. If I do

```
    * Hello|<C-CR>
```

I get

```
    * Hello
    * Hello
```

with the cursor on the second `*`, and I am in normal mode.

Weirdly, if I enter the commands by hand, it works for both kinds of lists. Why doesn't this work in a mapping?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround, works for your both cases, even thought is it a bit dirty. :-)

```
imap  <c-cr> <esc>YpA1<esc>^<c-a>$x0WC
```

Comment: I think the problem is not with recognizing the `<C-Enter>`, it is that it works with numbered list but fails in bullet lists.

Comment: @mMontu now I see what's OP's problem, added a solution.

Comment: Took me a while to parse and understand what's going there. Really cute. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Right, so [mMontu mentioning the 'beep'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25531680/2905010) led me to [this wiki entry](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_2%29#Error_in_mapped_key_sequences) that directly addresses my problem. So now I use

```
inoremap <buffer> <C-CR> <ESC>Yp:exec "normal! \<C-A>"<CR>WC
```

to "wrap" the error in an exec command, which doesn't produce a beep/error. I feel disgusting now, but does what it's supposed to, so I guess it'll have to do.

Answer (score 0):

When executing `<C-A>` in a line without a number to increment it gives a beep.

This same beeps appears when your mapping is executed on the bullet list. This fail on the  `<C-A>` command is aborting the execution of the remaining of the mapping.

You could use a `:substitute` command to do the increment, using the 'e' flag to avoid stopping in failure, as suggested in [Vim-FAQ 11.15](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-11.15):

```
inoremap <buffer> <C-CR> <ESC>Yp:s/\v(\d+)/\=submatch(1)+1/e<CR>WC
```

This alternative has the side effect of changing your `@/` register (the pattern used on the last search with `/` or `?`). If this bothers you could save its contents before performing the substitution and restore it at the end.

Comment: This works to an extent; problem is that if the numbers are padded (001, 002, etc), this mapping destroys that. *sigh* I'm sure there's a way around that as well, but that's more programming than I'm willing to invest here. However, your mention of the 'beep' led me to a solution that works around that, so thanks for that. :)

Comment: @wldmr I'm glad you figured it out